# RxJava Merge Flowable and Completable

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a `Flowable` that continuously emits items and never calls `onError` or `onComplete`. Now I have a `Completable` that I would like to merge with this `Flowable` so that when the `Completable` completes the `Flowable` calls `onComplete`. I cannot directly change the `Flowable` object that is given to me.

One issue I am having is that I would have used `takeUntil` on the `Flowable` however the `Flowable` may stop emitting items at any point and I would still like the `Completable` to be able to call `onComplete`.

Update:
Since we can do `Completable.toFlowable()` we are able to merge two `Flowables`. The issue is that I still cannot find a way to complete both when one completes.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, you cannot change the original `Flowable` itself, so it will not emit `onComplete`. You can have however make the resulting `Flowable` emit it by doing the following (pseudocode):

```
val f: Flowable = ...
val c: Completable = ...
val r: Flowable = f.materialize().mergeWith(c.materialize()).dematerialize()
```

Comment: This does not accomplish my functionality as mergeWith(Completable) requires the flowable to also finish

Comment: Have you tried? It does not require flowable to finish.

Comment: I have tried and the docs for `mergeWith` says "completes only when the other CompletableSource completes as well"

Comment: This should not matter because we dematerialize materialized onComplete from Completable. Anyway, you can try the static .merge() method.

Comment: .merge() waits for both sources to complete still

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalized solution. As noted in @Maxim's answer `merge`/`mergeWith` does not accomplish my functionality because it requires both the `Flowable` and the `Completable` to finish. This solution also handles disposing of both properly.

```
    Flowable<Integer> f = Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3);
    Completable c = Completable.complete();

    final PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    final CompositeDisposable cd = new CompositeDisposable();
    Flowable result = subject
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> {
                cd.add(f.subscribe(subject::onNext));
                cd.add(c.subscribe(subject::onComplete));
            })
            .doOnDispose(cd::dispose)
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
```